# Return database connection from function

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to return $db connection from function, so that I could use it in another function. But someone functions don't understand $db variable.

```
function dbConnection(){
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = '...';
   $dbpass = '...';
   $dbname = '...';

   try {
     $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=UTF8", $dbuser, $dbpass);
     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     return $db;
   } catch (PDOException $e){
     echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
   }
}
```

Then use it in all of my functions.

```
function getCurrentFile(){
   dbConnection();

   $stmt = $db->prepare(...);
   $stmt->execute();

}
```

Are there more preferable way to handle db connections? I used to require_once config.php(where is only db connection) file every time, but I don't want to do it anymore.

Comment: you might wanna look at using classes

Comment: Use a class then,  have a construct function which establishes the PDO connection.  From there,  you'll be able to use it anywhere else within the class and outside as well

Comment: I would recommend using a tried and tested db-abstraction library instead of running your own database code, since there are many pitfalls regarding security etc.

Comment: You need to look into scopes ([here's the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)) ... your variable $db only exists in the scope of the dbConnection() function. You are returning it, but you're not storing it in the other function. You're also creating a new connection every time you call your function instead of reusing the same connection, which is really bad when it comes to performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options is define singletone class providing database object:

```
// File: DbConection.php

class DbConnection
{

    /**
     * @var \PDO
     */
    private static $pdo;


    private function __constructor()
    {

    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(null === self::$pdo) {
            self::$pdo = new \PDO('....);
        }

        return $self::pdo;
    }

    private function __clone()
    {

    }

    private function __wakeup()
    {

    }
}
```

If you are using composer tool, add this line to composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "path_to_your_file/DbConnection.php"
    ]
},
```

In your project, on bootstrap include generated by composer vendor/autoload.php file and start using class by:

```
use DbConnection;

DbConnection::getInstance();
```

in whole projec.

Answer (score 0):

Write down your db connection code in class and create object to use everywhere else in your system.